# How to use cgitb for enhanced traceback logging in a flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, flask, traceback, cgitb

When exceptions occur in my Flask app I want to be able to use cgitb for enhanced traceback logging when exceptions occur.

Simply doing

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(format="text")
```

at the top of the file where the app is initialized is not doing the trick. I am still getting the standard python traceback when an exception occurs.

There could be an issue caused by how I currently have logging set up in my application, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
streamHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:% (message)s'))
app.logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/')
def main_route():
    a = 0
    b = 2
    c = b / 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I'd expect the traceback results to be like:

```
$ python3 cgitb_local_vars.py

ZeroDivisionError
Python 3.7.1: .../bin/python3
Sun Dec  9 10:46:17 2018

A problem occurred in a Python script.  Here is the sequence of
function calls leading up to the error, in the order they
occurred.

 .../cgitb_local_vars.py in <module>()
   18 def func1(a, b):
   19     c = b - 5
   20     return func2(a, c)
   21
   22 func1(1, 5)
func1 = <function func1>

 .../cgitb_local_vars.py in func1(a=1, b=5)
   18 def func1(a, b):
   19     c = b - 5
   20     return func2(a, c)
   21
   22 func1(1, 5)
global func2 = <function func2>
a = 1
c = 0

 .../cgitb_local_vars.py in func2(a=1, divisor=0)
   13
   14 def func2(a, divisor):
   15     return a / divisor
   16
   17
a = 1
divisor = 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
    __cause__ = None
    __class__ = <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
    __context__ = None
    __delattr__ = <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __dict__ = {}
    __dir__ = <built-in method __dir__ of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __doc__ = 'Second argument to a division or modulo operation
    was zero.'
    __eq__ = <method-wrapper '__eq__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __format__ = <built-in method __format__ of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __ge__ = <method-wrapper '__ge__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __getattribute__ = <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __gt__ = <method-wrapper '__gt__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __hash__ = <method-wrapper '__hash__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __init__ = <method-wrapper '__init__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __init_subclass__ = <built-in method __init_subclass__ of
    type object>
    __le__ = <method-wrapper '__le__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __lt__ = <method-wrapper '__lt__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __ne__ = <method-wrapper '__ne__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
    __reduce__ = <built-in method __reduce__ of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __reduce_ex__ = <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __repr__ = <method-wrapper '__repr__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __setattr__ = <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __setstate__ = <built-in method __setstate__ of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __sizeof__ = <built-in method __sizeof__ of
    ZeroDivisionError object>
    __str__ = <method-wrapper '__str__' of ZeroDivisionError
    object>
    __subclasshook__ = <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type
    object>
    __suppress_context__ = False
    __traceback__ = <traceback object>
    args = ('division by zero',)
    with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of
    ZeroDivisionError object>

The above is a description of an error in a Python program.
Here is
the original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cgitb_local_vars.py", line 22, in <module>
    func1(1, 5)
  File "cgitb_local_vars.py", line 20, in func1
    return func2(a, c)
  File "cgitb_local_vars.py", line 15, in func2
    return a / divisor
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

**Demo Code**

```
from flask import Flask
import cgitb
import logging
import sys
cgitb.enable(format="text")

app = Flask(__name__)
streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
streamHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:% (message)s'))
app.logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    a = 0
    b = 2
    c = b / a


@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    a = 0
    b = 2
    c = b / a
    return 'Success'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005, debug=True)
```

**Result**

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 182.4505.18)
 * Serving Flask app "flask_app_demo" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
pydev debugger: process 36941 is connecting

 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 334-725-940
10.81.19.181 - - [30/Jan/2019 17:46:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1811, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2087, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/flask_app_demo.py", line 18, in before_request
    from _pydev_bundle import fix_getpass
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: This is not an answer (I do not have enough reputation to comment), but please note that cgitb might be deprecated in Python3.8 and removed in Python 3.10:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0594/#cgitb